# why in julia Tracker.update!(W,-alpha*gW) and W = W - alpha * gW behaved differently?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am very new to julia. While following tutorial in [https://www.math.purdue.edu/~allen450/ML-with-Julia-Tutorial.html](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Eallen450/ML-with-Julia-Tutorial.html),

```
Tracker.update!(W,-alpha*gW)
```

and

```
W = W - alpha * gW
```

behaved differently. With `W = W - alpha * gW` we can not loop the code again it gives

```
"KeyError: key Tracker.Tracked ...."
```

while `Tracker.update!(W,-alpha*gW)` works fine. Why this is so?

Comment: Hi, please use markdown apostrophes to format the code (see my edit). Flux has had many updates in recent year - most likely this tutorial is outdated but maybe other people will comment more.